# IntelliJ IDEA Reporting Contract Violation Warning

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Here is the Java code:

```
public static boolean anyEqual(Object needle, Object... haystack) {
    if(needle == null || haystack == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if(haystack.length == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    for(Object match : haystack) {
        if(match != null && needle.getClass() == match.getClass() && needle.equals(match)) {
            return true; // warning from IntelliJ here, 'contract clause !null, null -> false is violated'
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is being shown? `contract clause !null, null -> false is violated`? Thanks!

IntelliJ 14.0.2 build: 139.659

Screenshot: [image]

Comment: Is there any annotation above the method?

Comment: Looks like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-136079, fixed in 14.1 EAP at https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+14.1+EAP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IntelliJ is inferring the formal [contract](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/10/better-control-flow-analysis-with-contract-annotations-and-intellij-idea-13/) of your method to be this:

```
null, _ -> false; !null, null -> false
```

What this actually means:

- The first contract specifies that, so long as the first parameter is `null`, it will return `false`.  This is observed by your first `if` statement:

  ```
  if(needle == null || haystack == null) {
      return false;
  }
  ```
- The second contract specifies that, if the second parameter is `null`, then it will return `false`.  This is also specified by the same `if` statement above.

My gut is telling me that IntelliJ is having some trouble discerning what the loop's formal contract is in addition to all of the above, although it'd be as simple as another condition in the contract expression.

```
for(Object match : haystack) {
    if(match != null && needle.getClass() == match.getClass() && needle.equals(match)) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Let's briefly go through this.

- The enhanced-for statement won't fire if `haystack` is of length 0, so that's something to take into consideration.
- The elements inside of the array could be `null`, and I'm not entirely sure that IntelliJ's static analysis covers that piece yet.
- We've established already that `needle` must be non-null, so there's nothing violating the contract at that line.
- If we have a scenario in which `match != null && needle.getClass() == match.getClass() && needle.equals(match)` is `true`, we return `true`.  Otherwise, we return `false`.

There's [nothing that I can see in the formal documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/contract-annotations.html) that gives us the expression we require to say, "hey - we're checking elements of an array!"; it may be the case that the analysis is tripping up on the fact that we're returning `true` in spite of what we stated above (since `haystack` is non-null).

Allow me to stress this point:

**`haystack` has to be non-`null` in order for you to enter into the enhanced-for.**  Your code will not work otherwise.

All in all, I wouldn't worry about it.  Better yet, file a bug against it so that this sort of thing could be fixed or expanded upon.

Comment: Link to IntelliJ Contract annotation documentation is broken. [Current version here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/contract-annotations.html).

Comment: @Flavin:  Thanks, but in the future you could suggest an edit.  I'd have likely approved that one.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an IntelliJ bug to me, since by removing the `static` keyword from the method the warning disappears.

Something must be confusing the static analysis here. One can always submit this to youtrack so jetbrains devs can look at it.

Someone already reported this issue [Here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-127667)

(tested on v14.0.3)

Comment: Or change the return type Boolean, and return Boolean.TRUE, it will go away as well.

Answer (score -3):

This message is being shown because IntelliJ checks for method contract violations. It's a relatively new feature, read more at https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/annotation_java.html

Comment: So yes, we can understand it's a feature.  What we want to understand is *why* it's behaving this way.